# In facebook-How can I get if the user is admin of the page using javascript?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have created application and page in facebook .Then added application into the page and also I have assigned two more user as a admin for that particular page.

I have used the below code for getting admin of that page

```
FB.api({

method: 'fql.query',

query: 'SELECT page_id, type from page_admin WHERE uid='+id

},
function(response) {

   if(response.length){
        alert('User is an Admin');
    }
    else{
        alert('User is not an Admin')
    }
}
);
```

This code getting the admin of that page only for current session user(that is me),not an other two person.

but that two person also admin of that page.but this code display "user is not an admin".

I want to display two person also admin of that page.

how to display other two person also admin of that page?

Please give me some suggestion or ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe if you allow the `manage_pages` permission you'll have more luck.  Here is a link to the facebook documentation detailing the `Page` endpoint and what properties you can get from it.
[Facebook page documentation - admins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#admins).
To get the full list of admins you might have to select all of the pages members
 and run this test on them :

> To check if a specific user is an admin of the Page, issue an HTTP GET
>   request with the appropriate PAGE_ID, Page access token, and USER_ID
>   to    https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/admins/USER_ID